# Ordering MongoDB collection by size of nested array

Tags: java, mongodb

Is it possible to order a MongoDB collection by the size of a nested array? Say for example we have a collection of Question documents and each document has a nested array of answers. I want to be able to sort the collection and pull out the most answered questions? I have been looking around and I am not sure its doable directly from MongoDB and I think it would be quite performance intensive to extract all questions and then sort them in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cann't query by size of nested collection, you need to create field with size of collection for such needs([mongo db documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size)):

> The $size operator matches any array
>   with the specified number of elements.
>   The following example would match the
>   object {a:["foo"]}, since that array
>   has just one element:
>
> db.things.find( { a : { $size: 1 } }
>   );
>
> You cannot use $size to find a range
>   of sizes (for example: arrays with
>   more than 1 element). If you need to
>   query for a range, create an extra
>   size field that you increment when you
>   add elements.